# Installing keystone.js

Tags: linux, node.js, keystonejs

I am having trouble installing **keystone.js** on Linux. Not really sure exactly what the problem is as I am very new to Linux. Here's the output below when I try to install keystone using `npm install -g generator-keystone`

I solved some issues with the answers from this: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)
but still getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-keystone"
npm ERR! cwd /home/emile
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/emile/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a general npm issue. Do you get similar errors when installing say `expressworks`?

Comment: Just installed express.js with no problems

Comment: but did you install it globally? like say `npm install -g yo`

Comment: Yes, I pasted "npm install -g generator-keystone" from the keystone.js site.

Comment: err I mean did a global npm install finish without error? e.g. yeoman?

Comment: Ok, just tried, it's failing with yo as well using: "npm install -g yo"

Comment: this thread is probably the solution to your problem. Do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: Thanks, but still getting some errors, made some edits to the question

Answer (score 1):

This link solved this exact issue for me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keystonejs/zZdSoz_sIn0

In short, the following spell solved the issue for me:

```
root@localhost:~# which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
root@localhost:~# cd /usr/bin/
root@localhost:/usr/bin# ln -s nodejs node
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it with sudo.

The line

```
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

Means NPM does not have sufficient permissions to create a new directory

The error log itself is telling you what to do.

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: That's a bandaid. You *shouldn't* be using sudo to install npm global modules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: Thanks, that worked great right until the end, now I'm getting this:                                                             npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
 
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: The npm warning is usually due to installing node from just doing "sudo apt-get install node" which installs an out of date version. You need to purge node/npm from your system, then I would reccomend using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), or just add the node PPA:

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install node

Comment: Thanks, but still getting some errors, made some edits to the question